# I explicitly close my Cursor and Database but still get not closed exception

Tags: android, sql

I have seen similar questions on this topic, but no definitive answer. I get an SQL exception saying that my database wasn't closed, when I stop and restart my Android app. I am sure I am doing what I should be to close the database and the Cursor. Please can you see if I have missed anything.

In my main activity, I have:

```
... <snip> ...
onCreate() {
    ... <snip> ...
    mDbHelper = new myDBAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    ... <snip> ...

    Cursor dataCursor = mDbHelper.fetchData();
    startManagingCursor(dataCursor);
    ... <snip> ...
    stopManagingCursor(dataCursor);
    dataCursor.close();
}

onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mDbHelper.close();
}
```

And in my DBAdapter activity, I have:

```
public myDBAdapter open()
        throws android.database.SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
    Log.v(CLASS_NAME, CLASS_NAME + " Closed the database helper");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to surround with try/catch/finally blocks...although sometimes I also get warning, using this approach. Nevertheless, using finally guarantees that close() will be called.

```
        try {
            cursor = callLogsSQLitedb.query(TABLE_NAME, from, null, null,
                    null, null, orderBy);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                //do stuff

        } finally {
            Log.d(TAG, " Closing cursor...");
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. So, the exception occurs on the mDbHelper.open() line before the Cursor stuff. I can see that I am closing the mDBHelper onDestroy() and onPause(), because I log it. The cursor stuff that I put inside the try block does not fail.

Comment: you can apply exactly the same approach to the database. You just need to make sure, that after you call close() on it, nothing will try to operate with it, without opening a connection again. My approach for now is always to make database calls using AsyncTask, thus I always close the database in the onPostExecute() method of the asyncTask. Keep in mind, that when you execute DB Call on your activity, it's executed on the UI thread. This freezes your activity, while the DB operations completes. You should consider using separate thread for DB operation. AsyncTask is very convenient for that.

Answer (score 0):

*onDestroy()* is not guaranteed to be called. Specifically, it won't be called if your activity is not destroyed between app launches. Maybe use `onPause()` instead.